# How to get min value of a column which is present in three different table for a particular record

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have three tables. These tables need not to have common members.

First is Opt_Out table:

```
**MemberId**         **Opt_out_Date**  
123               12-Jun-2014  
234               7-Dec-2014  
789               10-March-2014`
```

Second is Cov_End table:

```
  **MemberId**        **Cov_End_Date**  
     123               30-Jun-2014  
     234               31-Dec-2014  
     345               30-Sept-2014  
     891               30-Oct-2014
```

Third Table is Decsd_Date table

```
 **MemberId**          **Deceased_Date**  
   123                 23-Jun-2014  
   345                 17-Sept-2014  
   456                 23-Jun-2014  
   678                 25-Aug-2014
```

The result should be like this:

```
**MemberId**       **Min_Date**  
    123           12-Jun-2014    
    234           7-Dec-2014  
    345           17-Sept-2014  
    456           23-Jun-2014  
    678           25-Aug-2014  
    789           10-March-2014  
    891           30-Oct-2014
```

I want to achieve this result in best possible way and in single query.

Comment: Although this isn't probably the case for your question, but you should always add a tag for the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...). Very often answers depend on the DBMS being used or there is a more efficient DBMS specific solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the`union all`operator to merge the tables and use the result as a derived table:

```
SELECT MemberId, MIN(Date) AS "Min_Date"
FROM (
    SELECT MemberId, Cov_End_Date  AS "Date" FROM Cov_End
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MemberId, Opt_out_date  AS "Date" FROM Opt_Out
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MemberId, Deceased_Date AS "Date" FROM Decsd_Date
) src
GROUP BY MemberId
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38f13/1) (using MS SQL 2012)